# Homestead on Ubuntu not hot reloading JS files

Tags: javascript, laravel, ubuntu, homestead, hot-reload

I'm working on a Laravel project with a homestead setup on Ubuntu, and I'm only working on the JS files of the project. The JS files are in vendor folder since they are from different repos (I'm not experienced in this, so I'm not sure what can have the effect)

When I make an edit it's not hot reloaded, but if I kill node and `npm run start` (which runs `craco start`) again the edit is shown.

I tried using ChatGpt to fix it and here's his suggestions that I tried and didn't work:

1. Use NFS instead of the default file system.
2. Increase the inotify limit.
3. Use a different file watcher (this I couldn't do because I couldn't install and use the watcher it suggested which was another headache)

Also, I work on the same project on a Macbook with a Valet setup and the hot-reload works just fine with the same file structure.

Follows is my craco.config.js:

```
module.exports = {
  style: {
    postcssOptions: {},
  },
  webpack: {
    configure: {
      resolve: {
        symlinks: false,
      },
      ignoreWarnings: [{ message: /Failed to parse source map/ }],
    },
  },
};
```

I think a crucial part is that we are using symbolic links for linking the folders, and BTW we use craco since we use Fuse template which uses craco.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: `npm run start` is a script in `package.json`. We cannot guess what's in there until you show the code. Is it using webpack? How is the hot reloading set up? Check `package.json`. Javascript being in the vendor folder is... something new. It's usually from the `node_modules` folder or maybe `resources/js`. After compiling or `npm run watch` it ends up in the `public` directory of the Laravel project

Comment: @UnderDog Thanks for the reply, I edited the question. npm run start runs `craco start`. And yes I'm pretty sure webpack is used. And regarding the vendor folder I think all the project is connected through it as packages and the JS is in the assets folder of each package.
I hope this clears things up.

Comment: I think maybe based on @UnderDog mention of webpack I could dig something up. I think maybe I have an issue as described in [this link](https://github.com/laravel-mix/laravel-mix/issues/1147) but I'm not sure yet how to follow the mentioned solution.
I can see in my DOM the following `<script src="http://website.test/assets/layout/js"></script>` which seems problematic based on the mentioned link.

Comment: I found [this](https://github.com/laravel-mix/laravel-mix/issues/1468) too, but using browsersync didn't help, I'm still not sure what to do.